# Display inline not working, styling with Sass

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to build this drop down navigation bar, I am using Sass for the styling and jQuery for the drop down effect. I am trying to make the navigation bar inline however it is not working too well for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!--Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navigation_bar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> |
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li> |
            <!-- <div class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">sub_link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub_link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub_link</a></li>
            </div> -->
        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li> |
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> |
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is the Sass:

```
    @mixin navigation_bar {
    nav {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;

        ul, li {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline;

            a {
                font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #a4a4a4;
                padding: 30px;

                    &:hover {
                        color: #000;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.navigation_bar {
    @include navigation_bar;
}
```

Comment: By removing `clear: both;` all li items will on one line.

Comment: I actually tried that before and it didn't work. @KheemaPandey

Comment: The problem is what exactly?  "Doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description.

Comment: have a look. http://sassmeister.com/gist/cc547f63689fc2741c8e

Comment: Yes, I can see that the elements are inline.  That doesn't explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: is dropdown not working?

Comment: @cimmanon why you are doing counter attack on my comments.

Answer (score 0):

working example below

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqFom)

```
@mixin navigation_bar {
    nav {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            font-size: 0;

            li {
              display: inline-block;
              vertical-align: top;
              &:first-child a {
                background: #ddd;
              }
            }

            a {
                font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #a4a4a4;
                padding: 30px;
              background:#ddd url('http://i.imgur.com/tY2FYyp.png') left 50% no-repeat;
              display: block;

                    &:hover {
                        color: #000;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.navigation_bar {
    @include navigation_bar;
}
```